# Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen "wohingegen" und "hingegen"

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen 2 Wörtern (Ich weiß, dass die Wortstellung geändert wird, also Unterschiede außer das)?

Man vergleiche

> Im ersten Satz füttern wir den Hund, wohingegen wir im zweiten dem Hund Fressen geben

mit

> Im ersten Satz füttern wir den Hund, hingegen geben wir im zweiten dem Hund Fressen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es gibt keinen Unterschied. Das *wo* fügt lediglich "Funktion" hinzu, nicht Bedeutung.

Comment: und die Funktion ist die Wortstellungänderung?

Comment: @thekeyofgb ... naja, eher die Verbindung. Das "wo" zeigt auf den Fakt des ersten Satzes. Es ist ein Relativpronomen und die Wortstellung ist nur ein Nebeneffekt. Aber ja, die Wortstellung macht ja stilistisch einen großen Unterschied

Comment: Also, sind die Wörter auswechselbar, oder gibts Feinheiten, bei denen eines eher, als das andere verwenden würde?

Comment: @thekeyofgb.. ne, die Wörter sind NIE auswechselbar. Wenn dann die Konstruktionen ;). Meiner Ansicht nach gibt es keine Feinheiten. Die "hingegen"-Version ist einfacher zu bilden und einfacher zu verstehen und sie vermeidet Schlangensätze. "Wohingegen" allerdings lässt sie schön betonen und hat ein bisschen mehr Punch. In einer Diskussion ist es super, da der andere die Klappe halten muss bis das Verb kommt. Im Roman fände man eher "hingegen", in der Politik "wohingegen".

Comment: vielen Dank! wunderbare Erklärung